# After server reboot the server is now in desktop mode and no ssh works or ehternet

Tags: server, ssh, reboot

Yesterday I rebooted my ubuntu server with the command `sudo reboot now` but then I could not ssh back to it after waiting. It seems like websites running on the server with nginx still work.

When I physically went to my server this morning it gave me a desktop enviorment for some reason. Also in that desktop enviroment I can only change settings from the desktop enviroment I can't open things like vim which do show up in as installed in the desktop enviroment. The desktop enviroment also says that the ethernet is not working.

What should I do? How can I atleast get a shell going?

Also when it boots it says

```
Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server

`systemctl status ssh.service` for details.
aufs aufs_fill_super:918:mount[1429]: no arg
overlays: missing `lowerdir`
```

How can I be able to enter commands again?

Comment: You will want to start by talking to anyone else who might have physical (or remote) access to that server. Desktops do not get installed on server installations unless a person with `sudo` privileges specifically requests it. Once you know who did what, then you’ll be in a better position to reverse things out 

Comment: It might have been me but I don't remember. It was definitly not meant to happen. It probably happened monts ago and now because of the reboot something changed.

Comment: Can you open a terminal application from the desktop?  This would give you a command line.  Alternatively try control-alt-Fn2 to switch to another console not running the desktop.

Comment: @SEWTGIYWTKHNTDS I can not open anything on the desktop enviorment I will try the ctrl-alt-fn2 thing